# Excel --- Tried many time but fail

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDeNZ.jpg)

I want to sum all these data given in right side to my format. I tried many time and many formulas but some things left every time. Please help

Comment: which Column do you want to sum or are you looking to sum all the numbers. Also add sample Data

Comment: With the information you have provided it's not possible for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve most of what you need with a mixture of formulae and a pivot table.  But I couldn't quite get everything you wanted, as some of it doesn't make sense.  For example, you have 2013 - 2012 - <5 as your first row header, but there are multiple years that give an age less than 5, e.g. 2014 - 2013 - <5 would also be valid.  I would suggest hardcoding the years somehow, as they aren't entirely relevant anyway?

Breaking it down into separate problems.

How do I get the Roman number version of the Class?

You could have a massive `IF` statement, but I went for a `VLOOKUP`.  You could have used the `ROMAN` built in function, but you can't because your numbering is "first", "second", etc. instead of "1", "2", etc.

So I actually went for both solutions, just to show how they both work.  First I created a named table (list object) called "Named" that looks like this:

```
Class   Class Number
First   1
Second  2
Third   3
Fourth  4
```

etc.

I then used this to `VLOOKUP` your class names and convert them into numbers.  Next I used the `ROMAN` function to make this into roman numeral format.  So I ended up with this (columns E, F and G in my worksheet):

```
Class   Class Number    Roman
First   1               I
First   1               I
First   1               I
First   1               I
First   1               I
Second  2               II
Third   3               III
Fourth  4               IV
```

With formulae:

- Class Number - `=VLOOKUP(E2,Named,2,FALSE)`;
- Roman - `=ROMAN(F2)`.

How do I get from "Male"/ "Female" to "B"/ "G"?

This was trivial, just `=IF(A2="Male", "B", "G")` where I have Gender in column A.

How do I get the "age text" so it handles "<5" and ">22"?

My age was in column D, so this was also trivial, `=IF(D2<5,"<5", IF(D2>22, ">22", D2))`.

Now I have enough data to pivot, so I selected my entire table, which was basically your sample data with calculated columns added to the right.  Then I inserted a pivot table and dragged in row/ column headers to make it match your format.  This doesn't give you the year columns, but it gives you everything else.  For example, just using a few random rows of sample data (as I couldn't be bothered to type it all in):

I went from:

```
Gender  Date of Birth   Age Class
Male    06-Jan-14       4   First
Female  07-Sep-11       6   First
Male    01-Jan-12       6   First
Male    31-Dec-12       5   First
Female  01-Oct-11       6   First
Female  16-Nov-10       7   Second
Male    31-Oct-09       8   Third
Male    25-Oct-10       7   Fourth
```

To:

```
        I       II  III IV
        B   G   G   B   B
<5      1               
5       1               
6       1   2           
7               1       1
8                   1   
Total   3   2   1   1   1
```

From here you could simply hardcode the columns A and B from your desired final format, as these years aren't actually based on the data?